# Why does diskless system doesn't contain IP address?

Tags: computer-networks, ip

I am studying about RARP.

> What is the IP address of a given hardware address? Used by diskless systems to find their own IP address.

[https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/bnr/ftp/f15_arp.pdf](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Ejain/bnr/ftp/f15_arp.pdf)

So, why do diskless system doesn't have IP address? What does it even mean to be a diskless system?(Is it hard disk less system). If so, why does that mean that device doesn't have IP address? Is IP address assigned based on hard disk?

Comment: A device without read/write storage can't store device-specific configuration, so it needs to ask the network what its IP address is. RARP and DHCP can both achieve this.

Comment: Note that my laptop *does* have a disk, but it still gets its IP address from the network, not from a configuration that I wrote. In fact, I would guess that is true of most personal computers.